# Vertica-cluster architecture

Tags: vertica

I know that MongoDB has master-slave architecture and Cassandra has peer to peer architecture.

I didn't find any resources about Vertica's architecture.

Is that master slave or peer to peer?
Does Vertica cluster allow multi-read and multi-write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no concept of Master in Vertica.

But there is the concept of **Initiator** - this node will be the node who receives the connection and will compute the query plan, divide the workload among the nodes and then gather the result sets and format the output.

As for the multi-read and multi-write. Vertica is fully ACID complaint, this articles will give you more info.
https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ConceptsGuide/Other/Transactions.htm

Comment: Thanks :)  
by multi-read  i meant if we can divide connections and send to NODE 2 or NODE 3

Comment: Hy,Yes is possible as Vertica has Native Load Balancer (must setup on both sides Client and Server)

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [another answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/185914/45319), a Vertica cluster doesn't have a single master but has an initiator node that manages an operation using multiple nodes.

Vertica can parallelize a load if the data is available to multiple nodes.  Nothing's going to help you if the data you want only exists on one local file system, but if it's in a shared location, you can take advantage of that.  See the documentation of the COPY parameters "ON ALL NODES" and ON NODE {node-set}" -- [guide](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/BulkLoadCOPY/SpecifyingCOPYFROMOptions.htm%3FTocPath%3DAdministrator%27s%2520Guide%7CBulk-Loading%2520Data%7C_____7), [reference](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/COPY/Parameters.htm%3FTocPath%3DSQL%2520Reference%2520Manual%7CSQL%2520Statements%7CCOPY%7C_____1).

While you might not want to write your own data-loading extensions, you might also find the [UDx documentation on load-parallelism](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ExtendingVertica/UDx/UDL/ParallelLoad.htm%3FTocPath%3DExtending%2520Vertica%7CDeveloping%2520User-Defined%2520Extensions%2520(UDxs)%7CLoad%2520(UDLs)%7CLoad%2520Parallelism%7C_____0) interesting.

Comment: so if i do 
COPY t FROM 'file1.txt' ON (v_vmart_node0001, v_vmart_node0002);
so data will be inserted only on node01 and node02 but not on node03 ??

Comment: @shyamrakhecha once data is in Vertica it's visible on all nodes.  What that statement means is that node1 and node2 will be the only nodes that participate in the load operation.